# Angular 7 mock and return value for window location search using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spyon

Unit test for angular 7 with Jasmine. I need to set the `window.location.search` value in Jasmine.

I tried the following scenarios.

```
window.location.search = '?param=part1' 
// It's not working. Browser reloaded or disconnected the unit test cases.

spyOnProperty(window.location, 'search').and.returnValue('?param=part1');
// Disconnected the unit test cases.
```

How can I set the `window.location.search` value?

Comment: Does it not work if you omit the first line of code completely (`window.location.search = '?param=part1'`) ?

Comment: its disconnected the unit test cases